# Customizing the date filter menu in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I'm stuck on this ExtJS grid date filtering and will really appreciate some help.

My goal is to remove the "Before" and "After" submenu items and to show only the "On" item (even better is to remove the entire submenu and just show the datepicker).

So my question is if it's possible to remove those items and how can I do it? 
I tried with the menuItems config `menuItems: ['eq']` and this works visually, but when I select some date from the datepicker I receive this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'up' of undefined`.

[Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kb7)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in the Date filter component on the "onMenuSelect", it tries to unselect both "before" and "after" menu itens if you choose the "on" option, but you had those removed in the config.

I did a little override to fix this:

```
    Ext.override(Ext.grid.filters.filter.Date, {

            onMenuSelect: function(picker, date) {
                var me = this,
                    fields = me.fields,
                    filters = me.filter,
                    field = fields[picker.itemId],
                    gt = fields.gt,
                    lt = fields.lt,
                    eq = fields.eq,
                    v = {};
                field.up('menuitem').setChecked(true, /*suppressEvents*/
                true);


                //The problem ocurrs here, i modified this line
                //if (field === eq) {
                //**********************************************
                if ((field === eq)&&(lt!=null)&&(gt!=null)) {

                    lt.up('menuitem').setChecked(false, true);
                    gt.up('menuitem').setChecked(false, true);
                } else {
                    eq.up('menuitem').setChecked(false, true);
                    if (field === gt && (+lt.value < +date)) {
                        lt.up('menuitem').setChecked(false, true);                           
                        if (filters.lt.getValue() != null) {
                            v.lt = null;
                        }
                    } else if (field === lt && (+gt.value > +date)) {
                        gt.up('menuitem').setChecked(false, true);                           
                        if (filters.gt.getValue() != null) {
                            v.gt = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                v[field.filterKey] = date;
                me.setValue(v);
                picker.up('menu').hide();
            }
        });
```